# How to fix this "Couldn’t get file path for photo" while trying to open camera with react-native-image-picker?

Tags: android, react-native, android-camera, android-fileprovider, react-native-image-picker

I am using `react-native-image-picker` for capturing and storing the image to some location. In some devices the `error: Couldn’t get file path for photo` is coming even if `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` was already mentioned in the application tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I searched into some github discussions, I found one answer where a FileProvider path value has to be mentioned in the android resources folder. But the `FileProvider` value is already mentioned in the `react-native-image-picker`. I can't figure out why the error was coming. (Found the above error while running on Samsung galaxy M31)

The current build.gradle contains these `ext` properties

```
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
```

Comment: Also please share the targetSdkVerion used, as `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` no longer works when targeting sdk 30 or greater.

Comment: @ 
Nitish. No it still works. Keep it. It is needed for your app to run on Android 10 devices and only there. Further it does not harm.

Comment: @blackapps , but it will only work for Android 10 devices, on Android 11 device it won't work.

Comment: @Nitish added targetSdkVersion

Comment: @blackapps Added the error